# Aligning columns html

Tags: html, css

I'm using an unordered list to create a table. In the first row I only need 3 columns. All the other rows should have 4 columns but I cant align the first row to the first 3 columns of the other rows

```html
<ul class="table">
  <li>
    <span class="cell">Name</span>
    <span class="cell">Country</span>
    <span class="cell">Age</span>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form>
      <span class="cell"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" value="Ankit" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell"></span><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="" value="India" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell"></span><input type="text" name="age" placeholder="" value="20" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell_buttons">
                    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                    <button class="save">Save</button>
                    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                </span>
    </form>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form>
      <span class="cell"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" value="Shawn" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell"></span><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="" value="Canada" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell"></span><input type="text" name="age" placeholder="" value="26" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell_buttons">
                    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                    <button class="save">Save</button>
                    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                </span>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Noah and welcome to SO. Could you explain *why* you're not using a `<table.` element to create a table? Could you also create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the CSS that accompanies your HTML?

Comment: For a start, remove all the extra`</span>` in the subsequent rows.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of extra `</span>` in your code. Remove those and the extraneous `form` tags.

Then use CSS Tables.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0em;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
  text-align: center;
}

li span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul class="table">
  <li>
    <span class="cell">Name</span>
    <span class="cell">Country</span>
    <span class="cell">Age</span>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="cell"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" value="Ankit" readonly></span>
    <span class="cell"><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="" value="India" readonly></span>
    <span class="cell"><input type="text" name="age" placeholder="" value="20" readonly></span>
    <span class="cell_buttons">
                    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                    <button class="save">Save</button>
                    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                </span>

  </li>
  <li>

    <span class="cell"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" value="Shawn" readonly></span>
    <span class="cell"><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="" value="Canada" readonly></span>
    <span class="cell"><input type="text" name="age" placeholder="" value="26" readonly></span>
    <span class="cell_buttons">
                    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                    <button class="save">Save</button>
                    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello? Just do like this if you dislike to delete  tags. Let you change only CSS.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.table li {
  display: flex;
}

.table li span {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="table">
  <li>
    <span class="cell">Name</span>
    <span class="cell">Country</span>
    <span class="cell">Age</span>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form>
      <span class="cell"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" value="Ankit" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell"></span><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="" value="India" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell"></span><input type="text" name="age" placeholder="" value="20" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell_buttons">
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="save">Save</button>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
      </span>
    </form>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form>
      <span class="cell"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" value="Shawn" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell"></span><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="" value="Canada" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell"></span><input type="text" name="age" placeholder="" value="26" readonly></span>
      <span class="cell_buttons">
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="save">Save</button>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
      </span>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you don't want to delete form tag, just change the CSS like above.
If you want to add some effects according to the width of window, please use flex-shrink or flex-grow property in CSS...